# Wie lerne ich fließend zu sprechen?

Tags: spelling

Was sind die Bausteine? Wie kann ich richtig aufbauen?
Was könnt ihr mir empfehlen?
Ich habe viele Vokabeln gelernt. Jetzt höre ich Aufnahme

Comment: Sprichst Du, nimmst es auf, und kontrollierst dann die Aufnahme? Oder was hörst Du? Radio, Fernsehen, Video, Podcasts, Hörbücher?

Comment: Sprechen lernt man durch Sprechen. Skype + ein interessierter Muttersprachler wirkt Wunder; nur ein Auslandsaufenthalt ist noch wirksamer.

Answer (score 2):

Das Lernen von Fremdsprachen klappt für mich sehr gut durch Lesen und Fernsehen. Natürlich kannst du auch gut durch Gespräche mit Deutschen lernen, falls du jemanden kennst.